# How do I fix Cross-Site Scripting for number field in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```html
<form [formGroup]="studentForm">
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Notes</mat-label>
    <textarea
      matInput
      formControlName="notes"
      required
      rows="5"
      maxlength="1000"
    >
    </textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

i am getting cross site scripting issue for student id in create and update api .

```js
function create(){
  this.studentForm.controls['studId'].setValue(parseInt(this.stdService.studentID));
  this.subscriptionthis.httpService.sendReq(api.createStuNotes,this.studentForm.value).subscribe((data) => {});
}
```

I am getting cross site scripting issue for number field only.

Comment: That's a chunk of code, not a XSS issue. It isn't clear why you think you have an XSS issue. There's no code there which would directly inject HTML/JS into the page.